# What is the best way to read an xml file when there is no standard schema?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

I am working on an application in which, i have to read XML files that have a different set of nodes each time, although only a certain number of nodes appear in all the files, the combination in which they appear keep on changing, the XML files are generated by another system which i cannot control, I am looking into Linq to XML and XML serialization, but i guess serialization is not a choice since it needs pre-built classes to create objects.

Example XML data

```
<Employee>
  <PersonalInfo>
    <FirstName>Vamsi</FirstName>
    <LastName>Krishna</LastName>
  </PersonalInfo>
  <EmploymentInfo>
    <Department>
      <Id>101</Id>
      <Position>SD</Position>
    <Department>
  <EmploymentInfo>
</Employee>
```

Another Format

```
<Employee>
  <PersonalInfo>
    <FirstName>Vamsi</FirstName>
    <LastName>Krishna</LastName>
  </PersonalInfo>      
</Employee>
```

You can observe that `EmploymentInfo` node is completely missing in the second example, there are many number of combinations in which the XML data can be presented to the application, I have to read the XML file validate it insert into an SQL Server database through my C# code.

Comment: How does that not make it having a standard schema? Missing elements (optional elements) are explicitly supported by schemata. it has a schema, just you sometimes see only part of it used.

Comment: @TomTom those I added were just sample snippets they are not the real files, as i said the combination in which the nodes appear keeps on changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it depends.

If you just want to communicate with another system in a strongly-typed way, and you can expect the XML schemas to not be changing very frequently, you might be OK with XML serialization. Just encapsulate the deserialization into a separate component and write different versions of them (yes, you'll need to be able to determine the schema version that is currently used). I mean, each version would have it's own set of classes that are targeted by the serializer.

But if you really cannot infer a system out of the schemas used by the external app and need some intelligent parser, you'd better use XPath or Linq to XML or some other XML-level APIs to manually handle the XML-s.

BTW, both of your samples are pretty easy for the `XMLSerializer`. In the second case it will just set `EmploymentInfo` to null.

Comment: 1. Looks ti me it HAs a standard schema, just the OP does not know it and does think all elements are required.

Comment: I don't have the complete schema to build a class file out of it, but the XML elements keep on changing and the client is not providing me any schema file, he say he doesn't have one

Comment: But if the elements KEEP changing no code in the world will work flawless. The client must at least settle for a stable set of elements.

Comment: I totally agree with TomTom. It's the basics of the software architecture: if you have a public interface that is used by external applications, you should make your best at keeping the rate of changes as low as possible. Otherwise, the external apps get troubles. You should probably negotiate this requirement with the owners of the system you interop with.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a parser class wich ueses [.Net Xpath implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx). The parser should test the child elements for specific nodes before processing the data.

Visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471.aspx) for the complete syntax.

**Update**

A little example what i would do to solve the problem. At first, some Model classes to hold some data:

```
public class PersonalInfo 
{
   public string FirstName { get; set;}
   public string LastName { get; set;}
   // more properties
}

public class EmployeeModel 
{
    // remove List<> if you always just have 1 personalinfo child element
    public List<PersonalInfo> {get; set;}   
    public List<EmploymentInfo> {get; set;}
    // more properties
}
```

Now your "Parser":

```
public class MyParser
{
    // load xml string or xml file in constructor
    public MyParser(string xmlSource) { .. }


    public EmployeeModel GetEmployeeModel()
    {
         var result = new EmployeeModel();
         // use what ever you want to select nodes from your xml
         // and set data of result

         return result;
    }
}
```

In your productive code you can use this parser class to get a model of your xml data.

Comment: is linq to xml helpful in this scenario ?

Comment: If you are familiar with linq, you can consider to use linq to xml, but: linq to xml is just to SELECT XML Nodes, if you try to select "EmploymentInfo" of your second example, your result should be null - and your parser still needs to check that

Comment: Shouldn't i check whether the result is null using a linq query, go from there rather that create my own Parser ?

Comment: Thats exactly what i meant ;) Ill make a update to my answer to make it more clear

Comment: but to build the model class i need to have the schema which i don't have

Comment: Why the heck do you need a schema? Build it yourself with code logic and set the properties of your model manually.

Comment: To create the model manually, i guess you need to know what element will come when and where, that is what i need the Schema for, anyway thank you for the time you spent on answering my silly question